# GCC-4.9 Fails to Make Ruby 2.1.1 with Rbenv in OS X 10.9.2

Tags: c++, ruby, compiler-construction, rbenv, gcc4.9

I'm out of my depth here as I don't know jack about C and such compilers, except that as per tut's I've read - I've homebrew installed gcc-4.9, linked it, and in my .bash_profile have cc=gcc-4.9 - hoping this would allow me to install Ruby 2.1.1, as previous attempts have failed, complaining about the following:

```
note: unrestricted unions only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
```

I've visited the gcc site and seen that 4.9 includes c++11 support, so I'm confused as to why it's failing to make Ruby as per above error, and full error output below:

```
 make
CC = /usr/local/bin/g++-4.9
LD = ld
LDSHARED = /usr/local/bin/g++-4.9 -dynamic -bundle
CFLAGS = -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings   -pipe 
XCFLAGS = -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -fno-strict-overflow -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT -fPIE
CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1g/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-darwin13.0 -I./include -I.
DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -L/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1g/lib  -fstack-protector -Wl,-u,_objc_msgSend -pie -framework CoreFoundation  
SOLIBS = -lgmp 
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/local/bin/g++-4.9
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc49/4.9.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0/4.9.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Configured with: ../configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc49/4.9.0 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++ --program-suffix=-4.9 --with-gmp=/usr/local/opt/gmp4 --with-mpfr=/usr/local/opt/mpfr2 --with-mpc=/usr/local/opt/libmpc08 --with-cloog=/usr/local/opt/cloog018 --with-isl=/usr/local/opt/isl011 --with-system-zlib --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-stage1-checking --enable-checking=release --enable-lto --disable-werror --enable-plugin --disable-nls --enable-multilib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.0 (GCC) 
compiling miniprelude.c
In file included from vm_core.h:24:0,
             from miniprelude.c:8:
method.h:84:19: error: member 'rb_method_attr_t rb_method_definition_struct::<anonymous union>::attr' with copy assignment operator not allowed in union
rb_method_attr_t attr;
               ^
method.h:84:19: note: unrestricted unions only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
In file included from miniprelude.c:8:0:
vm_core.h:674:59: error: use of enum 'iseq_type' without previous declaration
VALUE rb_iseq_new(NODE*, VALUE, VALUE, VALUE, VALUE, enum iseq_type);
                                                       ^
vm_core.h:677:76: error: use of enum 'iseq_type' without previous declaration
VALUE rb_iseq_new_with_bopt(NODE*, VALUE, VALUE, VALUE, VALUE, VALUE, enum iseq_type,     VALUE);
                                                                        ^
vm_core.h:678:75: error: use of enum 'iseq_type' without previous declaration
VALUE rb_iseq_new_with_opt(NODE*, VALUE, VALUE, VALUE, VALUE, VALUE, enum iseq_type, const rb_compile_option_t*);
                                                                       ^
make: *** [miniprelude.o] Error 1
```

As I wrote, I'm really out of my depth here, so would appreciate any help resolving this so I can install Ruby 2.1.1.

My ./configure command used is:

```
./configure --prefix="$HOME/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1" --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1g
```

I installed Rbenv via homebrew, so it's bin isn't in ~./rbenv but in my PATH and sym linked by homebrew from:

```
/usr/local/bin/rbenv -> ../Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/bin/rbenv
```

I can't see any complaints about that, which makes me think I'm possibly using the wrong C-compiler, but I don't see others with the same errors, and they are happy with homebrew's gcc-4.9 or apple-gcc42, but to be honest - I have no idea how to determine which to use.

Any help appreciated as I've wasted far too long on this instead of actually developing a web app.

Thanks

Comment: Why is it trying to use g++?

Comment: Why are you trying to use GCC at all? Just use clang.

Answer (score 0):

The error message

```
 note: unrestricted unions only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
```

says that some feature is available, only when `gcc` (or `g++`) is started with options `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11`

So, gcc 4.9 includes c++11 support, but not enables it by default. Add command line option `-std=c++11` to enable the support. Such options are usually included into `CFLAGS` variable. Or you can even try to add this into your CC.

I think there can be error in Ruby's `configure` script. This script should check for all needed features and cook right set of flags to `CFLAGS`, but in your case it failed to add `-std=c++11` into flags.

Comment: I suspect that the build should be using gcc rather than g++. As far as I know, Ruby is written in C.

Comment: @osgx: Thanks, I should have mentioned I had already tried installing gcc49 with: brew install gcc49 --enable-languages=c,c++,c++11 but this didn't help. So, I did this wrong? Should I reinstall it like so? brew install gcc49 --enable-languages=std=c++11 ? Sorry, I'm out of my depth here.

Comment: @kec Thanks, but all the Ruby installation tut's I've seen refer to installing gcc, not g++, but to be honest I don't even know the difference between the two of them. I'll google 'install ruby g++' now, but I think osgx is likely more on the right track.

Comment: @user3591456: Exactly, so it seems you should be using `gcc`, not `g++`, which is what you are doing. It appears that you are trying to compile Ruby with `g++`, which is the C++ compiler that comes with the GCC compiler suite. But as far as I know, Ruby is written in C, which means that you should be using `gcc`, which is the C compiler that comes with the GCC  suite.

Comment: @kec Thanks, I first tried making Ruby with gcc4.9 without any config options other than pointing to the homebrew openssl dir. So I'm confused - how can I ./configure gcc to just use C?

Comment: @user3591456: Well, I've never compiled Ruby, but if you point me to which one of these instructions you followed, then I might be able to help: https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/installation/.

Comment: @user3591456: I took a quick look at some of those instructions. Somwhere, somehow, it seems that you set/configured something to make it use g++. I noticed that you show this line: `CC = /usr/local/bin/g++-4.9`. Normally, `CC` should be set to point to the C compiler, not the C++ compiler.

Comment: @kec Thanks - it's installed. I uninstalled homebrew's gcc49 and commented out the additions tut's said to include in my .bash_profile: export CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9 export CC=/usr/local/bin/cpp-4.9 export CC=/usr/local/bin/g++-4.9, and instead relied on xcode's linked compiler. I'd previously tried a tut that said to only put CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9 in bash_profile, and that didn't work, and nor did using homebrew's applegcc42. My guess was that because gcc can compile C to C++ etc, as its site says, the build script would choose the right language. But I'm a noob at C and Ruby.Thanks!:)